# A call to SSPI failed - The certificate is revoked

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications

My application was working fine two days ago. I was able to sent the push notification completely fine on live app but suddenly i starts getting this error

> {System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The certificate is revoked

Here is my code, where i am getting the exception

```
 try
    {
       stream.AuthenticateAsClient(this.appleSettings.Host,
         this.certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls,
        false);                 
    }
 catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
   {
      throw new ConnectionFailureException("SSL Stream Failed 
    to Authenticate as Client", ex);
   }
```

The tried to change the  `X509Certificate` to `X509Certificat2` and  `X509CertificateCollection` to `X509Certificate2Collection` but it didn't help me. I also did not revoked any certificate from my developer account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had the same problem, We fixed it by generating the new .p12 certificate file for Apple push notification. Validity of certificate is of one year and it is independent of your app. So you **don't** need to up the app gain on store to fix the issue. Just find the app id of your app. Use this app id to create a new .p12 certificate file for push notification and upload it on your server.